# CMake internal target types

Tags: cmake, target

The CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/TYPE.html) for the TYPE property says the following (emphasis mine):

> The type of the target.
>
> This read-only property can be used to test the type of the given target. It will be one of STATIC_LIBRARY, MODULE_LIBRARY, SHARED_LIBRARY, EXECUTABLE or **one of the internal target types**.

What is an "internal target" and what types can it have?
I do not seem to find any information about this.

Comment: I tried to query this property on a custom target and the result was "UTILITY". Therefore I believe a custom target has "one of the internal target types".

Comment: I interpret "one of the internal target types" as "types of other targets are **implementation-specific**. They could be silently changed in newer CMake versions, so no one should assume any specific value."

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think you are right. However, I wanted to know what targets would have these implementation-specific types. And due to my "experiment", I believe a custom target is one of them.

Comment: `I wanted to know what targets would have these implementation-specific types.` - Every target except of specified types. And yes, custom target is one of them.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you.